# msoShapeOval entered in cell not allowed to be value for variable declared as MsoShapeType

Tags: excel, vba

In the attached code everything works except assigning the value to shpOval3.

I am trying to take the text from a cell and assign it to a variable declared as MsoShapeType.

1) The code misfires with Type mismatch when it attempts to assign the cell value of msoShapeOval to shpOval3 (declared as MsoShapeType).

2) If I try strOval4 (string) instead in `.Shapes.AddShape(strOval4, Left, Top, Width, Height)` it also misfires and says Type mismatch.

I am trying to avoid converting to an msoShapeType constant in the cell as the cell value is loaded into a combobox on a form and the value of 9 is meaningless to the users. I can convert if necessary but am looking for a solution without converting.

```
Sub ShpType()

Dim shpOval1 As Long
Dim shpOval2 As MsoShapeType
Dim shpOval3 As MsoShapeType
Dim strOval4 As String

Sheets("Data").Range("Company1Shape") = "msoShapeOval"

shpOval1 = msoShapeOval
shpOval2 = msoShapeOval
shpOval3 = Sheets("Data").Range("Company1Shape")
strOval4 = Sheets("Data").Range("Company1Shape")

Debug.Print "shpOval1 = "; shpOval1
Debug.Print "shpOval2 = "; shpOval2
Debug.Print Sheets("Data").Range("Company1Shape")
Debug.Print "shpOval3 = "; shpOval3
Debug.Print "strOval4 = "; strOval4

End Sub
```

```
Debugger results with shpOval3 commented out
shpOval1 =  9 
shpOval2 =  9 
msoShapeOval
shpOval3 =  0 
strOval4 = msoShapeOval
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Select Case statement to test your string and assign the appropriate constant to a variable declared as msoAutoShapeType...

```
Dim strShapeType As String
strShapeType = Sheets("Data").Range("Company1Shape")

Dim shapeType As MsoAutoShapeType
Select Case strShapeType
    Case "msoShapeOval"
        shapeType = msoShapeOval
    Case "msoShapeRectangle"
        shapeType = msoShapeRectangle
    'etc
    '
    '
    '
End Select
```

Hope this helps!